# Как сделать "preview" камеры в imagebox?

Tags: java, android, камера, android-camera, preview

Скажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать, чтобы изображение с камеры было в imagebox?

*Сразу скажу, в интернете я уже почитал как отдельно запустить камеру и потом просто вгрузить в imagebox, но это не то, мне нужно чтобы в нашем activity была превьюшка.*

*Была идея делать фото с быстрой частотой и маленьким разрешением (чтобы была "типа" превью камеры), но я думаю это убого будет.*

Comment: Что такое imagebox?

Comment: @eugeneek imageview

Comment: Никак. Для этого можно использовать `SurfaceView`. [Пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/264-urok-132-kamera-vyvod-izobrazhenija-na-ekran-obrabotka-povorota.html)